# Legal Issues Concerning Intellectual Property

Tags: license

I'd like your opinion.

When a GIS Analyst leaves their job, are they allowed legally to take with them odds and bits they collected or made during their  work (small stuff like e.g. small VBA/Python scripts, examples of complex labels), or like all their bigger Projects it is copyrighted and belongs to the hiring Company?

I mean, it's clear that they can't take programs, layers and big stuff (or secret data for that matter), but what about the small non-specific odds and bits?

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what the intellectual property policies are - usually they're pretty unambiguous - **all** the work done while in the employ of company "A" are the property of company "A", regardless of any copyright notices (or lack thereof) in the source files. No policies (probably) means that it's whatever state law says it might be, if it's even addressed clearly.

As seen in any number of larger lawsuits (the SCO suits come to mind), it'd be really hard to **prove** that someone walked off with a bunch of subroutines or scripts, and probably not worth it. It seems to me that most of these nigh-trivial items would be either easily duplicated from memory or would possibly even exist already in company "B", thus making a claim of serious harm done very difficult. I do know of some companies that have filed suit for these same items so in the past, so it not unheard of.

Oh, and IANAL, etc., etc., so none of this is worth the bits it's stored with. Personal experience and conjecture only.

Answer (score 4):

@Herb's answer generally tracks with how I understand it. As an extension, anything developed by a consulting company for a customer belongs to the customer that funded the work so, in this case, the employee's work doesn't even really belong to the employer.

It is also true that this stuff is very hard to prove and is generally left alone but, if the company feels the long-term value is worth the near-term legal costs, they could pursue something. (See Intergraph/Bentley)

In the case of Jay's example of stuff that in your brain, that is basically correct but it gets muddier if the thing that's in your brain is a copyrighted/patented technique or piece of logic belonging to your previous employer. If you use that knowledge to reproduce something similar for someone else, then there could be liability.

Like Herb, IANAL. Years ago, when I worked for a big consulting firm, I had to sit through an internal training course on this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to ask questions on a site like this, then post the solutions as answers when you discover them.    That way your “odds and bits” are then in the public domain.

Just don’t post anything that your boss is not happy with!

Answer (score 0):

You could argue that if it is impossible for the hiring company to prove that the odds and bits was developed during the hire, how could it possibly be their property? I think the boundary between knowledge and physical code is very unclear on the odds and bits level.

Its like copying copyrighted material - no one will directly loose value, but indirectly they might. And again when it comes down to odds and bits, I wouldn't think of it as a loss for the hiring company.